# renderInContext: function not working in Mojave 10.14.4

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-mojave

I am working on on camera application in which I want to take snapshot of OpenGLView and its subviews. Below code was working for me. When I had 10.14.2 after upgrade to 10.14.4 (renderInContext) function stopped working for me.
    Can you please help?

```
//captureImage is function which return Bitmap data which then convert to NSimage.
```

glView is my OpenGLView where camera feed renders

```
- (NSBitmapImageRep *)captureImage
 {
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[glView bounds].size];
    [image lockFocus];
    CGContextRef ctx = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext].graphicsPort;
    [glView.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    [image unlockFocus];
    NSData  * tiffData = [image TIFFRepresentation];
    NSBitmapImageRep * bitmap;
    bitmap = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:tiffData];
    return bitmap;
 }
```

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "not working"? Do you get error messages?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention. Function is to capture the image which was properly captured previouly but it now gives blank image/"White image"